# Modify a block face to a true circular path

Tags: modeling

In the picture, I beveled a block similar to the top block but it is not a true circle shape - it has a kind of shoulder and the top is flat.
I don't know how to take a block and modify it so the width and height stay fixed but it follows a true circular path - I do know the radius of the circle I need, but don't know where to go from here. [image: example]

Comment: 2D or 3D? Cylinder or Hemisphere??

Comment: This is a 3D shape - a little hard to tell from the picture. And it would be a Cylindrical slice that I would need.